# Info does not submit into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

We have an assignment for school and I've tried to build the application, however some text that I want to have inserted into a database doesn't get submitted.

I've tried different things, but the page does not show an error either.

This is the code of my insert page

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br/>
    Server: <input type="text" name="Server"><br/>
    Student: <input type="text" name="Student"><br/>
    Docent: <input type="text" name="Docent"><br/>
    Project: <input type="text" name="Project"><br/>
    Startdatum: <input type="text" name="Startdatum"><br/>
    Einddatum: <input type="text" name="Einddatum"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "serverruimte");
    if(!$con) {
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO serverruimte (id,Server,Student,Docent,Project,startdatum,einddatum) VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[Server]','$_POST[Student]','$_POST[Docent]','$_POST[Project]','$_POST[startdatum]','$_POST[einddatum]')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($result) {
        echo "Opslaan voltooid!";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, what happens is: https://i.imgur.com/aUOx5yj.mp4

Does anyone know what the problem is and why the inserted data does not show up on the index page? The data does show on the page when I submit it directly into the MYSQL database.

Comment: In addition to the current answer, you can also surround your variables with `{}` like `VALUES ('{$_POST['id']}','{$_POST['Server']}'`

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

When working with MySQLi you should enable automatic error reporting instead of checking for errors manually. Checking for errors manually is a terrible practice, very error prone and should be avoided at all costs. Let MySQLi throw exceptions and do not catch them. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

When opening MySQLi connection you must specify the correct charset. The recommended one is `utf8mb4`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Enable automatic error reporting
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    // Create new instance of MySQLi class
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "serverruimte");
    // Set correct charset. Important!
    $con->set_charset('utf8mb4');

    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO serverruimte (id,Server,Student,Docent,Project,startdatum,einddatum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $_POST['id'], $_POST['Server'], $_POST['Student'], $_POST['Docent'], $_POST['Project'], $_POST['startdatum'], $_POST['einddatum']);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Opslaan voltooid!";

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO serverruimte (id,Server,Student,Docent,Project,startdatum,einddatum) VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[Server]','$_POST[Student]','$_POST[Docent]','$_POST[Project]','$_POST[startdatum]','$_POST[einddatum]')";
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO serverruimte (id,Server,Student,Docent,Project,startdatum,einddatum) VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['Server']."','".$_POST[Student]."','".$_POST['Docent']."','".$_POST['Project']."','".$_POST['Startdatum']."','".$_POST['Einddatum']."')";
```

Reason behind this change is because your query is wrong for the following reasons:

- You were using strings instead of concatenating your real values coming from $_POST
- Some of your indexes in $_POST were misspelled. For example:

  `$_POST[einddatum] should be $_POST['Einddatum']`

Also, consider that this code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)